# Implementing startup tasks for SL5 OOB application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am putting together a Silverlight 5 application that will run out-of-browser and has a bit of everything on start-up.  Specifically, here are the steps I need to follow:

1. Check that the app is running out of browser (if not, display a screen instructing the user to install it locally).
2. Display a "splash screen" (it would be nice if this would play animations while the remaining steps execute).
3. Configure MEF
4. Pre-load context information and 'static' data from the server (for example, settings). This data is required before any of the application logic can run.
5. Dynamically load additional XAP files including an external theme library.
6. Replace the "splash screen" with the shell which contains a navigation frame.
7. Navigate to the application's start page.

I also need to support Application Extension Services (IApplicationService, IApplicationLifetimeAware) so any process I implement must respect these services. Most of these services will require MEF to be configured, so they should not execute before MEF has been configured and imports satisfied.

Another consideration is that some imports may be satisfied only after the dynamic XAP files have been pulled in and MEF recomposed.

One of the hurdles I'm running into is the fact that I cannot do step 5 until the previous steps are complete. Loading the XAP files or calling the server for data asynchronously allows the code to proceed. I need a way to "stall" the UI until all of the composition is complete and all required context data has been loaded.

So, I'm looking for recommended approaches that satisfy all of these requirements and am happy to provide more details if that helps get to a working solution.

**UPDATE**

The best explanation I can give for my difficulty is that I must 'release' the UI thread to display a 'splash screen' but also suspend the normal life cycle of the application while each step executes. I can't (and don't want to) do everything in the Application.Start event handler because application services will have already started.

Plus, releasing the UI thread means I do work in the background and let the original method (Application.Start, for instance) return and the runtime will move forward in the startup process. For example, starting a background process in the Starting method of an application service then returning allows the runtime to raise the Start event on the Application object. But if I need the background process to complete before I can do the next thing, I have to suspend the current thread which blocks the UI.

So I'm not sure how to divide up the work or where to put it (App, application service, bootstrapper, workflow, etc.).

Comment: Is that all? What have you tried?

Comment: I have performed most of the steps individually but not together. I've purposely not gotten into the various implementations because I am looking for what others have or would do rather than focusing on what I have or haven't done (especially since I haven't been successful at putting it all together).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManualResetEvent class to force the service calls to be Sync (and guarantee the order they complete). You could also use this to synchronize the background thread to the main UI thread.

http://mohundro.com/blog/2006/06/27/a-little-bit-about-manualresetevent/

Comment: My issue is not synchronizing the background thread with the main UI thread.  My problem is that the UI goes through a lifecycle (IApplicationService.StartService, IApplicationLifetimeAware.Starting, Application.Start, IApplicationLifetimeAware.Started).  I do not want Application.Start to occur until all of the operations being executed in the Starting have completed (for example) BUT I need the UI to refresh at some point so the 'splash' will display.

Comment: If I run any of these operations on a background thread, the UI thread will continue through the lifecycle and I won't have the intended workflow where operations occur in the sequence required to ensure that prior steps have completed.

Comment: You can't do this on the main UI thread in Silverlight, it's not possible.